# Xamarin iOS : Issue with DidReceiveChallenge while using NSURLSession API

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession

I am writing a Xamarin native iOS application and using nsurlsession to hit a http endpoint which gives me basic type authentication challenge.

My issue is that the DidReceiveChallenge method in my delegate is not being called:

My code:

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/test/test");
        NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
        NSUrlSession session = null;
        NSUrlSessionConfiguration myConfig = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
        MySessionDelegate myDelegate = new MySessionDelegate();
        NSOperationQueue myQueue = new NSOperationQueue();
        session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(myConfig, myDelegate, myQueue);

        NSUrlSessionTask task = session.CreateDataTask(request, (data, response, error) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("data is"+data+"response is"+response+"error is "+error);

        });


        task.Resume();
```

My Delegate class:

```
public class MySessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDelegate
{

    public override void DidReceiveChallenge(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("challenge is"+challenge.ProtectionSpace.AuthenticationMethod);
        base.DidReceiveChallenge(session, challenge, completionHandler);
    }


}
```

The application output I am currently getting:

```
data isresponse is<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170437700> { URL: http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/nsharma/P@ssw0rd } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Sat, 11 Feb 2017 03:18:45 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    Via = "1.1 nas58.airwlab.com";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Fake Realm\"";
} }error is
```

As you can observe, I can hit the url which issue a 401 due to basic auth challenge. Normally I would expect the flow to call DidReceiveChallenge method in my delegate instance but it never calls it and finishes the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Was using the wrong Delegate class:

```
public class MySessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDelegate{
public override void DidReceiveChallenge(NSUrlSession session, 
NSUrlSessionTask task, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, 
Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler){

}
}
```